# Open another Telegram chat/group/channel using Bot

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I suspect it may be rather kid question – but anyway.

How to open another Telegram chat or group or channel using pyTelegramBotAPI? I want to forward the user (not message, the user himself) to another channel if he clicks certain button.

I saw content type `migrate_to_chat_id` in Message class declaration. Should I use it? If so, how to get an id of channel I need? It won't send any message to my bot.

I would better use "*t.me/...*" url.

Answer (score 1):

Partly solved.

Speaking about the buttons, it is indeed easy. You just use named parameter `url=` in `InlineKeyboardButton()` method.

For other cases. You need to open another channel(s) from function depending on several conditions for instance. Still don't know. Import `requests` and make GET request? I suspect that something for it should already be in pyTelegramBotAPI, but searching in lib files wasn't successful.